# Regex to get single value from Json file using bash

Tags: linux, grep, aws, json

I would like to retrieve a value "tenki-deploy-topic" from the below JSON file content. I used this regex `grep -o 'topic[^"]*' output.log`, then it gets all the files with the topic, instead, I want to use some other key such as "tenki" or "dense".

```
{ "Topics": [ { "Name": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:topic-freezing-deploy" }, { "Name": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:topic-dense-deploy" }, { "Name": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:topic-tenki-deploy" } ] }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to use regular expressions, when `jq`, a purpose-built JSON parser, will do the job?

Comment: Question wrong?  Did you mean "topic-tenki-deploy" ?

Answer (score 5):

Using the typical CLI tools of Linux/Unix such as `awk`, `sed`, & `grep` are almost always the wrong way to go when trying to parse JSON.

My typical goto tool for JSON CLI work at the terminal is `jq`. It's in all the repos and can be easily installed.

Your problem of how to select just the elements in the `Topics` array becomes trivial:

```
$ jq '.Topics[] | select(.Name | contains("topic-tenki-deploy"))' output.log 
{
  "Name": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:topic-tenki-deploy"
}
```

The above works by taking the elements from the `.Topics[]` array and then selecting the `.Name` whose value contains `topic-tenki-deploy`.

#### References

- [Print array element if it contains #861](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/861)

Comment: +1 ... or `jq -r --arg str "tenki" '.Topics[] | select(.Name | contains($str)).Name | split(":")[-1]'` if you want to parameterize the search, and get the bare value of the last component of the Name string